# Environment variables in bit.dev

Tags: reactjs, bit.dev

I am using bit dev for microfrontend solution in my project and I want to use environment variables in my project but, when I tried the traditional approach of .env file it is not working and even there is nothing in their documentation, I am confused on how to use it.

I tried creating a .env file then adding my environment variables but that is not working at all, i am using reactjs for my project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.